# C# function changes and adds _1

Tags: c#

I have experienced this many times. With buttons and check boxes ect, and it just happened again. I have a simple function:

```
private void cbRunPSExec_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     StaticGlobals.RunPSExec = cbRunPSExec.Checked;
}
```

I make no changes to this code but I am making changes in other places of the program. Then all of a sudden things stop working correctly. When I go back to the designer and double click the checkbox I get this:

```
private void cbRunPSExec_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Then if I put the original code in this new code it again works. How does .Net lose it's reference to the original code?

Comment: Don't edit the auto-generated code, exactly because of this. If the filename has `Designer` in it, leave it alone. - That's not where you should put your code.

Comment: Did you delete the original checkbox?

Comment: No, never deleted any objects, they just lose the reference, and if you click the button or check box in the designer you get the _1. And I am not editing the generated code, only adding to it.

Comment: How did you create the first method, by double clicking as well? And did the original method disappear?

Comment: Yes put a checkbox on the form, then double click it to generate the event code. This check box was there for years, but it just stopped working and when double clicked again I get the _1 added.

Comment: the `_1` sounds like it still has that code somewhere with the original name, hence it add the `_1` to differentiate this new handler you just created.

Comment: This is because the ```CheckBox``` has lost attachment to the event handler and when you click it, it makes a new one.  The _1 is appended because it's still finding the original code.  Somehow in your process you are causing the ```CheckChanged``` event to lose the original binding so it quits working.

Comment: Is your class marked `partial`?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing "special" about designer generated code. If you look inside your CSPROJ file you can clearly see the declared dependency;

```
 <Compile Include="RenderDestinationWindow.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="RenderDestinationWindow.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>RenderDestinationWindow.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
```

In my case the RenderDestiationWindow has a dependency on the designer generated .Designer.cs file. The Visual Studio designer creates these files when you open your form/control in design mode and press Save.

When you open the form/control in design mode again, the code is compiled and evaluated through reflection within the designer, and the events hooked up to the designer user interface. In fact the design surface actually calls your code to render itself (this is why deleting an event handler in code instead of within the designer causes the designer to fault when opening the form - your code no longer compiles, so the designer cannot render it).

I have seen this fail in a number of scenarios; if I use visual inheritance or embedded child controls. Both of these can play very badly in the visual designer. Also opening the form/control and pressing "continue" on the "edit and continue" prompt if the compilation fails.

My advice is; always compile your code cleanly before opening a design window, and always close a design window after making any changes, and dont leave a design window open when you close visual studio.

In your case the fact that the designer adds "_1" to teh event handler indicates you have an event handler in your code already but the designer does not recognize it as being attached to the control named in the designer.cs file. If you look in the designer.cs file you wont see the event handler being added to the control within there; the designer.cs file is written every time you make any visual change in the design surface; and this is especially common if you inherit or embed controls/forms and try manipulating them through the parent/inheritor control or form.